# What are assumptions for logistic binomial regression if all independent and independent variables are dichotomous?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, classification, logistic-distribution

I have three independent and one dependent variables of the dichotomous type and I am trying to use logistic binomial regression. I have 117 observations in total.

When I read the literature, some of the assumptions of logistic regressions, where I am stack right now, are:

-**larger sample size** (if I understood it correctly, the sample size should not be less than 500 according [Sample Size Guidelines for Logistic Regression from Observational Studies with Large Population: Emphasis on the Accuracy Between Statistics and Parameters Based on Real Life Clinical Data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6422534/))

-**linearity of independent variables and log odds**

My question would be:

1. What should I do if I am restricted to those 117 observations and can not have 500 samples? Is there any approach to handle this situation? Am I still allowed to use logistic regression? If not, is there any other tool?
2. What assumptions do I need to test? Do I have to test linear dependency of independent variables to log odds, even if I am having categorical variables (with outcomes yes or no)?

I appreciate your input.

Comment: If the independent variables are all binary then linearity of their effects is a non-issue; there's only one possible way for their effect to manifest. Re: sample size, the question is how many 1s and 0s you have for each level of the three independent variables (and their interactions if you are including those).

Comment: Interactions are still an issue ... so additivity is an issue even if linearity is not.